# Closure Syntax Error F#

Tags: c#, ios, f#, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to implement the following C# code from the repository: https://github.com/alexsorokoletov/Xamarin.iOS.DatePickerDialog

in F#:

```
dialog.Show("Choose time", "Done", "Cancel", UIDatePickerMode.Time, (dt) =>
{
  TimePickLabel.Text = dt.ToString();
}, startingTime);
```

However, F# seems to only expect 3 arguments in the following format:

[image]

I understand how to fill in the `title` and `datePickerMode` arguments, however, I am a bit confused with the callback. I know I should use the `fun` syntax, so I tried like this:

```
datePicker.Show("FROM", fun() -> (
        Console.WriteLine("Testing")
    ),UIDatePickerMode.Date)
```

but this throws an error:

The Expression was expected to have type `DateTime` but has type `unit` in the brackets after the `fun`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback is supposed to take an argument of type `DateTime`, but yours doesn't.

Change it to `fun _ -> Console.WriteLine("Testing")` and it should work.